# Is it possible for one of a pair of muscles to feel the burn more than the other muscle in the pair?

Tags: muscle, burn

The last two times I've done legs curls at the gym my left glute will feel the burn on the third set, but the right glute did not even though I made sure that both legs were putting in the same amount of force.

After thinking about the last set I decided to do a fourth set with only the right leg doing the curl to get some burn.

So the obvious question as stated in the title. Is it normal for only half the pair to feel the burn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both muscles may not be of equal strength and ability. If you work them equally you may be able to even them out. This is definitely normal.

Comment: +1 Yes. It's normal for the muscles on one side of the body to be conditioned differently than the other. Also, it's possible that the parameters of the exercise may be different from one muscle to the next. Maybe one leg is slightly longer than the other (it's not that unusual!), maybe the curl machine is tilted slightly so one side has better leverage.